# How to download HTML source in Java when the page requires a sign in?

Tags: java, html, authentication, url, ntlm

Currently I am trying to download the html source of a webpage using a URL object and an input stream like below.

```
url = new URL(urlString));
            is = url.openStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while((tempLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                pageSource.append(tempLine);
            }
```

The webpage requires a username and password when you browse to it and appears with a pop-up menu when browsing normally, I have tried passing the username and password into the URL in the following format which has not worked.

*http://Username:Password@domain*

I currently get this error when using the code above

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
```

I would really appreciate any insights as to how to authenticate with the domain using my credentials so that I can download the page source.

Many thanks - James

Comment: We need more information. How is the authentication handled in that page? Why are you expecting it to work at GET?

Comment: Authentication is a simple username and password that appears in a pop-up dialog when using a regular browser, previously through selenium automation passing the credentials through the URL in the style mentioned above has worked perfectly, however using the same URL for the page source downloader encounters this 401 error

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be POSTing your credentials? Does the same request work on your browser? If not, then this isn't the correct way.

Comment: Have you tried sending the Basic Authentication headers? Basically send the header `Authorization: Basic ` followed by the string `username:password` encoded in base64. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ale Sanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3694355/ale-sanchez) for the pointer towards Authentication headers, I went into postman to probe the domain I was hitting and found it was using NTLM authentication instead of Basic authentication.

I came across this site [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) which gave some really examples for using NTLM authentication in Java and used the following code which works perfectly

```
static final String kuser = "username"; // your account name
static final String kpass = password; // retrieve password for your account 

static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
        // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
        System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
    URL url = new URL(args[0]);
    InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    String str;
    while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

Thanks to everyone who commented for their help :)

-James